# Amdatu Web using Jersey

Tags: java, jersey, osgi, apache-wink, amdatu

Amdatu web uses apache wink to create restful web app in OSGi. Recently the Apache Wink project retired - I don't know exactly why.

My question is: Can I use apache web for my production OSGi application? is the RETIRED apache wink with in amdatu web stable for production usage? and If not how to use other rest providers like Jersey?

Thanks

Comment: If you can wait for OSGi Release 7 (due 1st Quarter 2018) then you can use the new JAX-RS Whiteboard Specification. Alternatively Jersey can certainly be used directly in OSGi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the next Amdatu Web release of Apache Wink will be replaced by RESTEasy, you can't just drop in any provider so it won't be possible to use Jersey.

Furthermore we are updating the whiteboard implementation in Amdatu Web to implement the JAX-RS Whiteboard specification mentioned by Neil Bartlett.

Comment: Thanks, just a few days ago I checked the amdatu bootstrap. The repository was not there. Are you moving it somewhere else or ...?

Comment: We have been moving around some repo's to get the Amdatu user changed into a team in Bitbucket. Doing this we decided not to transfer some projects to the new team as we're not planning to put any effort in them.

You can still find the project in the new user account here https://bitbucket.org/amdatuadm/